Website metadata: not detected when Vue is used
I have a Vue project that consists of a single page all of which content comes from the public/index.html file. In particular, its metadata tags. However those tags are not parsed by social media (Discord) and by an online parser: https://jsonlink.io/.
Meanwhile a page.html file with the very same tags gets parsed (and embedded on Discord) alright.
The simple page.html (URL: http://lionchortle.lol/page):
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>

    <meta name="theme-color" content="#C41721"/>

    <meta property="og:url" content="http://lionchortle.lol">
    <meta property="og:title" content="Lion Chortle">
    <meta property="og:description"
          content="Lion stuff">
    <meta property="og:image" content="https://i.imgur.com/JvVi7Rr.jpeg">
    
       <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
 
    <meta name="twitter:url" content="http://lionchortle.lol">
    <meta name="twitter:title" content="Twitter title">
    <meta name="twitter:description"
          content="Twitter description">
    <meta name="twitter:image" content="https://i.imgur.com/JvVi7Rr.jpeg">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
</body>
</html>

Output from Discord:

Output from JsonLink parser:

Vue project (URL: http://lionchortle.lol/vue):
root
  public
    index.html
  src
    App.vue

index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
  <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Title</title>

    <meta name="theme-color" content="#C41721"/>

    <meta property="og:url" content="http://lionchortle.lol">
    <meta property="og:title" content="Lion Chortle">
    <meta property="og:description"
          content="Lion stuff">
    <meta property="og:image" content="https://i.imgur.com/JvVi7Rr.jpeg">
    
       <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
 
    <meta name="twitter:url" content="http://lionchortle.lol">
    <meta name="twitter:title" content="Twitter title">
    <meta name="twitter:description"
          content="Twitter description">
    <meta name="twitter:image" content="https://i.imgur.com/JvVi7Rr.jpeg">
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      <strong>We're sorry but <%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %> doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong>
    </noscript>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <!-- built files will be auto injected -->

  <h1>Vue Page</h1>

  </body>
</html>

Output from Discord (no embeds):

Output from JsonLink parser:

The meta tags are visible on View Source Code page for the Vue project, and are not loaded dynamically, so it shouldn't be a matter of SPA vs SSR.
However, I'm lost as to what is the issue here.

The difference between these pages is the existence of 